# Create a calculated column based off a substring of another column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, substring, calculated-columns

I'm trying to create a calculated column from a string of another column. The column looks like this:

```
PL00100-0705-1100
```

I want the new calculated column to be

```
05-11
```

I can add a new column and then run an update statement like below:

```
update table 1
set newcolumn = SUBSTRING(column1, 11, 5)
```

Is there a way to make that a calculated column so I don't have to run an update statement to achieve the desired results?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Sure - create a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
    ADD NewColumn AS SUBSTRING(column1, 11, 5) PERSISTED;
```

Now your table has a new column called `newcolumn` that will contain the defined sub string.

Of course - you might need to make this expression more resilient to cases when your `column1` doesn't have 16 or more characters.... - but the basic mechanism is like that - define a computed column that will automagically be calculated for you, without need for an `UPDATE` statement all the time...

Comment: Thank you very much, I had tried something very similar but I didn't have PERSISTED at the end.  Yes depending on the database I am in, each customer could have a different numbering system and would have to change the substring to match. Again thank you.  I have a similar question I will ask in a different question.